# e.preventDefault does load empty page without Ajax data

Tags: jquery

I used e.preventDefault() in Jquery to load an html page into a . The html page has some Ajax action that will get the data from the server. I got it works to display the page but not the Ajax data that it got. It seems to me that the page display in  happen before the ajax call back data. But with out the e.preventDefault, when click on the link, the page open a new page and it works with all the data it got back from ajax page. Any solution or help to delay the load page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function (e) {                    
        $("#content").load($(this).attr("href"));               
        e.preventDefault();      
    });             
});
```

Comment: have you tried putting the `e.preventDefault();` first and then the load method???

Comment: did that.. same result.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the page you are loading fires of the ajax requests as part of an event handler. E.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   fetchDataByAjax();
}
```

however that event won't befired when you load it through ajax. the document ready event already happened and it will only happen once.

To make it work you will therefor need to extra the javascript to a common place and include it in both pages. In one you would still execute the method(s) in the document.ready or what ever you use) while in the other you will execute it when you've inserted the html into #content